# Represent model graphically

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Java environments like BuleJ (https://www.bluej.org/) allow to visually see your objects and their properties and actions available on them:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Let's say I have a model Student in my application:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null = True, )
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null = True, )
```

Is there a way to represent objects of this model in such a graphical way? To see its attributes and methods, perhaps invoke them and so on? Can we do it in Django/DRF?

To me it seems like a view on this object that all stakeholders can understand.

Comment: An IDE like PyCharm has support to generate such diagrams. You can write them yourself by inspecting the model classes.

Comment: I long ago gave up expecting stakeholders to understand any tech stuff.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers my idea is that they don’t have to understand the tech part in it, code itself is the model of the domain as Domain Driven Design suggests and it should be possible to generate different representations of this underlying model suitable for each stakeholder to understand  like documents or UI etc.

Answer (score 0):

[django-extensions](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions) provides this feature. More details:

https://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/graph_models.html#graph-models